# How to change progress bar filler color instead of default green color

Tags: user-interface, android

I want to change the color based on the %age of progress bar.
Here is my code:

**xml**

```
<org.package.VerticalProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/Temp"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="51dip"
    android:maxWidth="100dp"
    android:minWidth="0dp"/>
```

This is how i am using it in my app:

```
private static VerticalProgressBar progressBar;
progressBar=(VerticalProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.Temp);
progressBar.setProgress(12);
```

What should I add here to set the color of the progressbar?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check out this [tutorial](http://www.learnandroideasily.blogspot.in/2013/05/custom-progress-bar-in-android.html)-[custom progressBar in android](http://www.learnandroideasily.blogspot.in/2013/05/custom-progress-bar-in-android.html)

//custom_progressbar.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- Define the background properties like color etc -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <gradient
                    android:startColor="#000001"
                    android:centerColor="#0b131e"
                    android:centerY="1.0"
                    android:endColor="#0d1522"
                    android:angle="270"
            />
        </shape>
    </item>

 <!-- Define the progress properties like start color, end color etc -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <gradient
                    android:startColor="#007A00"
                    android:centerColor="#007A00"
                    android:centerY="1.0"
                    android:endColor="#06101d"
                    android:angle="270"
                />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

and assign it from it your java code-

```
// Get the Drawable custom_progressbar                     
Drawable customDrawable= res.getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_progressbar);

// set the drawable as progress drawavle

progressBar.setProgressDrawable(customDrawable);
```